# Integrating FMOD sound tools into a game

Tags: makefile, g++, ubuntu-12.04, fmod

I did not find here a post here that has to do with FMOD and makefile, and I tried to get some help from the FMOD forum, but their database is down. So, here it is.

I'm working on a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit. I want to integrate FMOD sound functionality into an air hockey game. I have the functioning game and I have a functioning "example". I'm not very well versed in all sorts of makefile syntax and make-ing an FMOD application, which is why I'm here.

This is the makefile for the example:

```
x86: main.cpp
        g++ -O2 -m32 -o example $< ../../api/lib/libfmodex.so

x64: main.cpp
        g++ -O2 -m64 -o example $< ../../api/lib/libfmodex64.so

x86_c: main.c
        g++ -O2 -m32 -o example $< ../../api/lib/libfmodex.so

x64_c: main.c
        g++ -O2 -m64 -o example $< ../../api/lib/libfmodex64.so

clean:
        rm -f example
```

As I understand, the example makefile can determine what to load in based on what architecture and language you are using. I don't know what flags from the example makefile I should put in what list of flags of the air hockey makefile. I'm afraid to mess it up.

Also, I want to make sure that the game can run on any machine without ever having to refer to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` that may not exist on the machine.

Newbie here. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makefile will build, depending on which target you tell it, an example binary for one of two architectures from one of two source files. The choices are:

```
`x86` which builds a 32 bit program from the example C++ source file.
`x64` which builds a 64 bit program from the example C++ source file.
`x86_c` which builds a 32 bit program from the example C source file.
`x64_c` which builds a 64 bit program from the example C source file.
```

The main part of that code, as far as building your game with FMOD goes, is that it includes the appropriate FMOD shared object file in the compilation line (though in a way I don't normally see done).

You need to include a similar path to the appropriate library in your game's compilation commands or (likely if you are using an FMOD library that has been installed on your system) you just need to include the correct `-L` and `-l` flags to gcc/g++). `-L` to tell the compiler where to search for the FMOD library and `-l` to tell it what the library name is (either `-lfmodex` or `-lfmodex64` for those example cases).

Comment: I actually did add `-lfmod-4.44` to the lists of libraries and `-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib` to the list of compiler flags, but that didn't work. As for `-lfmodex` or `-lfmodex64`, I don't know which one to use, but maybe adding both could work. Also, I've added a few things to my post with regards to referring to FMOD headers and cpp files located elsewhere.

Comment: What does your current linking line look like? Does it fail? If so, how? The path at which a library is found during build-time linking does not matter for runtime library location. At runtime the system configured locations will be searched for appropriate libraries; if they are found things will work correctly. (A binary/library can include an explicit list of extra locations to check for libraries but that's a different topic, read about RPATH.)

Comment: The link line is: `$(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) ../src/main.cpp ../src/mesh.cpp ../src/texture.cpp -o ../bin/Matrix $(LIBS)`, and it's fine. It worked on previous revisions. Also, are you suggesting that RPATH is something I should use to allow the application find those libraries within its directory?

Comment: No. You don't need to use RPATH for your binary to find the libraries on systems if they are installed in normal system locations on those systems. In terms of `-lfmodex` or `-lfmodex64` that's a question for what architecture you are building for (though I would hope fmod wouldn't actually stamp their libraries like that so you don't have to care). You just need to include whichever -l argument refers to the fmod library you want to link against. I don't know which that is. I don't know fmod at all.